# putting colon inside array of integers

Tags: javascript, html, loops, ejs

I have this:

```
           <% var dates = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] %>
              <input type="text" name="city" list="cityname" placeholder="Start Time">
              <datalist id="cityname">
                <% for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { %>
                  <option value="<%= dates[i] %>">
                <% } %>
              </datalist>
```

but inside the `dates` array, i cannot put a colon. I want to do like `1,1:30,2,2:30`, and so on, but obviously i cannot. So what would be the best way around this?

Comment: You could use string ("1:30") and later convert that to any type you want

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution online. here's what it showed me:

```
<% var arrayOfTimes = []; %>
 <% for (var i = 0; i <= 24; i++) { %>
    <% var n = i%2==0 ? i/2+':00' : (i+1)/2-1+':30'; %>
       <% if(n<10) %>
         <% n = ''+n; %>
         <% arrayOfTimes.push(n); %>
         <% console.log(arrayOfTimes); %>
       <% } %>
              <input type="text" name="eventendtime" list="eventstarttime" placeholder="End Time" readonly>
              <datalist id="eventstarttime">
                <% for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfTimes.length; i++) { %>
                  <option value="<%= arrayOfTimes[i] %>">
                <% } %>
```

and `arrayOfTimes` is:

```
 [
  '0:00', '0:30', '1:00',
  '1:30', '2:00', '2:30',
  '3:00', '3:30', '4:00',
  '4:30', '5:00', '5:30',
  '6:00', '6:30', '7:00'
 ]
```